# sqlite cordova plugin multiple select

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I have a record that is populated from 4 tables.
Relation is one to many, so I need to execute 4 select statements.

As far as I understand db.executeSql and transaction.executeSql returns before result is fetched.
So, the code below may not be executed correctly as second select may be executed before first result is fetched.
So, the correct way is to perform second select in the success function of the first select, then third select in the success function of the second one etc.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Below is a code example:

```
getRecord: function(id) {
    var me = this, record;
    me.open();
    me.db.executeSql('select * from mainRecord where id=?', [id], function(res) {
        if (res.rows.length) {
            record = new Test.model.MainRecord(res.rows.item(0));
        }
    });
    me.db.executeSql('select * from subTable1 where recordID=?', [id], function(res) {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i=0;i<res.rows.length;i++) {
            arr.push(res.rows.item(i));
        }
        // here record may be null as this function mau be executed before first select returns some result
        record.set('subTable1', arr);
    });
    me.db.executeSql('select * from subTable2 where recordID=?', [id], function(res) {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i=0;i<res.rows.length;i++) {
            arr.push(res.rows.item(i));
        }
        record.set('subTable2', arr);
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "better"?

Comment: When I started to use sqlite plugin, i noticed that executeSql method is async, and if in the above example record may be null in the success function of the second sql (added a few more comments).